# Returns each array element 2 times using Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I have a method `public static Iterator<Integer> intArrayTwoTimesIterator(int[] array)` that take an array.
I need to returns an `Iterator` that iterates over given array but returns each array element 2 times.
For exemple array is `new int[]{1, 2, 3}`, and in output need to be `"[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]"`.
How to return elements 2 times using Iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this implementation:

```
public static Iterator<Integer> intArrayTwoTimesIterator(int[] array) {
  return Arrays.stream(array).
          flatMap(value -> IntStream.of(value, value)).
          boxed().iterator();
}
```

Comment: work perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate array and push each element after each element and return an array.

You can do this:
(How to insert an item into an array at a specific index)

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "1";
arr[1] = "2";
arr[2] = "3";


arr.join(); // Jani,Hege,Stale,Kai Jim,Borge
arr.splice(1, 0, "1");
arr.join();
```

Or Just push each element on iteration into array and sort them.